# Where is this fill function defined?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, geometry, bubble-chart

In the example, http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/bubble.html:

[image]

In line 27:

```
.style("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.packageName); });
```

Where is `fill()` defined? I didn't find it in `d3.js` either. And even if the package name is not a color, some random color is being assigned. How so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the very top of the snippet you linked:

```
var r = 960,
    format = d3.format(",d"),
    fill = d3.scale.category20c();
```

That third line is where `fill` is being defined. You can find the doc for `category20c` here:

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#wiki-category20

Answer (score 2):

The source code is on lines 2997- on [d3.v2.js](http://%20https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/d3.v2.js):

```
d3.scale.category20c = function() {
  return d3.scale.ordinal().range(d3_category20c);
};
```

Which is calling:

```
// lines 2894-2896
d3.scale.ordinal = function() {
  return d3_scale_ordinal([], {t: "range", x: []});
};
```

Which then calls

```
// lines 2903-2905
function scale(x) {
    return range[((index.get(x) || index.set(x, domain.push(x))) - 1) % range.length];
}
```

The parameter passed in, `x` is set to `d3_category20c` which assigns colors from the list of 20 available colors seen below:

```
["#3182bd", "#6baed6", "#9ecae1", 
"#c6dbef", "#e6550d", "#fd8d3c", 
"#fdae6b", "#fdd0a2", "#31a354", 
"#74c476", "#a1d99b", "#c7e9c0", 
"#756bb1", "#9e9ac8", "#bcbddc", 
"#dadaeb", "#636363", "#969696", 
"#bdbdbd", "#d9d9d9"]
```

Stepping through the code I see the colors assigned like this (based on the category passed in):

```
cluster = 0 #3182bd
graph = 1 #6baed6
optimization = 2 #9ecae1
animate = 3  #c6dbef
interpolate = 4 #e6550d
converters = 5 #fd8d3c
data = 6 #fdae6b
display = 7 #fdd0a2
flex = 8 #31a354
physics = 9  #74c476
query = 10 #a1d99b
methods = 11 #c7e9c0
scale = 12 #756bb1
util = 13 #9e9ac8
heap = 14 #bcbddc
math = 15 #dadaeb
palette = 16 #636363
axis = 17 #969696
controls = 18 #bdbdbd
render = 19 #d9d9d9
events = 0 #3182bd
legend = 1 #6baed6
etc...
```

Note, it's using the mod operator so it can keep assigning colors if the number of passed in categories exceeds the range of 20 colors.

Note, the colors for `d3_category20c` are defined in [category.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/scale/category.js), lines 48-54.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, this code:

```
var r = 960,
    format = d3.format(",d"),
    fill = d3.scale.category20c();
```

defines fill(). I just want to add following handy combination of documentation and reference card:

[image]